# Convert to decimal from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array as such:

```
int[] fourbits = new int[4];
fourbits[0] = neuroninputs.input1;
fourbits[1] = neuroninputs.input2;
fourbits[2] = neuroninputs.input3;
fourbits[3] = neuroninputs.input4;
```

Each element contains a binary value. For example :

```
Console.WriteLine(fourbits[0]);
```

outputs 1.

What I am trying to do is to take every value from this array(1010) and convert this to decimal and print this value(10).

Comment: You are aware that the smallest value that can be represented in a hexadecimal manner is a byte, which is 8 bit?

Comment: What is the Exception being thrown?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it might be better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/‎)

Comment: @aevitas Apologies, typo. I meant decimal.

Comment: @leppie The exception is index out of bounds. The modulus operator loops the array back to the start.

Comment: Well then you need an `if`, not a `try/catch`...

Comment: @leppie Oh okay thanks, I will try that. I'm guessing using an if statement will allow me to access only the code that is 'reached' and then I can do the conversion to decimal?

Comment: Hello commenters. Have edited my question. Hope what I am enquiring about is clearer now. Many thanks.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(string.Concat(fourbits), 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First concatenate all the bits into a `string` using `String.Join`,then use [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method specifying the `base` parameter.:

```
var value = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", fourbits), 2);

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

**Note:** You need to make sure that your array contains only `ones` and `zeros` in order to speficy base parameter as `2`. Otherwise you will get a `FormatException`.

Comment: You can use `string.Concat(fourbits)`, which is a little simpler.